# Dealing with PostgreSQL %ROWTYPE returns

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, dao, plpgsql

I've got a PostgreSQL function which looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunc() returns myTable as $$
DECLARE
my_row myTable%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
select * into strict my_row where......
return my_row
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Blame the user !'
USING HINT = 'Its always the users fault !';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The problem is, that when I call it in Java and I try to get an item from the ResultSet, e.g. `rs.getString(1)`, instead of getting that column, I get the entire row representation, i.e. `rs.getString(1)` yields a string that looks like like:

> "("col1data","col2data",etc. etc.)"

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Please show us the `select` statement that you use in your Java code.

Comment: I am not sure it matter what my function sql query is.  It is a standard multi-column SQL query with * as a column selector and a primary key in the where clause.  The Java code just calls "select function(Params)", as per normal PostgreSQL

Comment: It *does* make a difference how you call that function.

Comment: ok, apologies.  Pavel's answer made that clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got packed composite value. You have to unpack this value by `FROM` clause

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fx()
RETURNS foo LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT ROW(a,b) FROM foo LIMIT 1);
END;
$function$

postgres=# SELECT * FROM foo;
 a  | b  
----+----
 10 | 20
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT fx(); -- packed composite
   fx    
---------
(10,20)
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT * FROM fx(); -- unpacked composite
 a  | b  
----+----
 10 | 20
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel.  Will try your suggestion and let you know